# Error when clearing cache symfony

Tags: php, symfony, caching, terminal

I'm trying to clear cache after editing .yml files

First I locate installation folder using this command: `cd directory-path-here`

Then I enter:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - extension already loaded
>   Could not open input file: bin/console

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the [ionCube Loader](https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php) twice in your environment, check your `php.ini` and loaded modules for php.

```
grep -rniP ioncube {/etc/php*,/path/to/project}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Symfony 2, then try

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```